# Wants to store external file(.xml formate) into my sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, xml

Currently I am working in Sql server 2005. our client has to sent an xml file to our server. What I need to do to make my sql server to accept that 3rd party file?

Comment: This much description can't attract experts of stackoverflow..!!

Comment: Hi Abirami, could describe what you have tried so far?  In other words, are you trying to figure out how to start by getting the data into the database, or are you getting a specific error when  you do so?  Also, if you are trying to do this from T-SQL or a C# program, etc.. that would be an important detail to help people answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem storing XML in SQL Server 2005. You can put it in an XML column or just in a NTEXT or similar if you need to keep an existing schema.

Have a look at the reference here: [XML support in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify more about what you want to do with that data.

SQL Server supports an XML datatype which can store the contents of a file in a column.

You may want to parse and load the data from the XML representation into regular database tables according to some model.

SQL Server 2008 has some more options like FILESTREAM.